# Bug with empty div container in main site

Tags: bug, design

Noticed this a while back, forgot to say something (I think, could be dupe, no idea), but I have an empty `div` on my main site view underneath my favourite tags, and above the newsletter (which I have no intention of participating in, so it does me no good):

[image: Everyone Loves Stack Overflow]

The `div` class is `everyonelovesstackoverflow`, perhaps there's *supposed* to be something there but I don't love Stack Overflow enough to see it?

Edit: **sometimes** it shows up (apparently):

[image: I guess I love Stack Overflow now]

Do note: I have *really* slow internet (3Mbps) and if anything else is going on it's even slower.

**Browser**: Safari Version 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10)
**Operating System**: macOS Sierra Version 10.12

Comment: [Related: "Empty white rectangle in the new design"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6187/42401). I'm not VTC dupe as I'm getting the rectangle on FF + PB + ABP, and vanilla Chrome.

Comment: Looks like the [meta-tag:community-ads] slot. Also the newsletter is just a weekly email with links to the previous week's "greatest hits" and some unanswered posts, nothing to *participate in*, rather something to *subscribe to*.